# js scope and property enumeration

Tags: javascript, debugging, console, scope

Weird!

I am working on a plug in for Moodle using javascript. I am not an expert with js, just getting started. I have some debug code within a function on an object that is getting called :

```
    console.log(M.core_filepicker.instances);
    for (var clientid in M.core_filepicker.instances) {
        console.log(M.core_filepicker.instances[clientid]);
    }
```

The console.log bit outputs this :

```
Object
4e16f16a0dc14: FilePickerHelper
4e16f16a1837e: FilePickerHelper
4e16f16a03933: FilePickerHelper
4e16f169cd12c: FilePickerHelper
4e16f169d70e0: FilePickerHelper
4e16f169e2466: FilePickerHelper
4e16f169ed42e: FilePickerHelper
```

An 'Object' with property keys 4e16... etc and values for these properties of type FilePickerHelper.

But the for loop does not run.

The funny thing is in other scopes it does run and iterates through the properties. In the debug console in my browser or within other functions. I cannot understand why this would be.

Jamie

Comment: Are you sure that `Object` is not the printout of the first `log` statement and the `FilePickerHelper`s come from the loop? add an `alert('hey')` inside the loop just to make sure.

Comment: Yes, am sure the FilePickerHelpers are output by the first log call.

Comment: It'd be really funny if your object looked like: `{ prop: "4e16f16a0dc14: FilePickerHelper", prop2: "4e16f16a1837e: FilePickerHelper", etc }`

Comment: Interesting it turns out that the properties that I was trying to loop through had not had anything assigned to them at the time of the code being executed. **So this changes the nature of the question**, now the question for me is why the console.log call does show the properties as existing already when actually they don't!

Comment: I continued to ruminate on this question and resolved what was happening hopefully correctly here : http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=180893

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued to ruminate on this question and resolved what was happening hopefully correctly here : http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=180893

Comment: Please expand on what you discovered here, and possibly accept your answer if you think it is correct

Comment: I have found that both in Firefox and Chrome although more so in Chrome console.log is not necessarily reliable when used in an app with lots of closures and scope chains. It seems that console.log does not always show the value of the variable passed to it when it is called, it sometimes shows the value at a later time. For example in Chrome try :

`test = {};
console.log(test);
test.hello1 = "hello";
(function(){
    console.log(test);
})();`

Comment: It seems that using breakpoints to stop code at a point of interest and then viewing the variable contents is reliable though.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)

for (var i in myArray)
```

Are different constructs. It seems to me that your code inside the loop would prefer the first type of for.

What does

```
 for (var instance in M.core_filepicker.instances) {
        console.log(instance);
    }
```

give you?

(Ps be aware of hasOwnProperty() if doing a for in.)

Comment: `for (var instance in M.core_filepicker.instances) {
        console.log(instance);
    }`
When run in the console gives :

    `4e16f169cd12c
    4e16f169d70e0
    4e16f169e2466
    4e16f169ed42e
    4e16f16a03933
    4e16f16a0dc14
    4e16f16a1837e`

Comment: But the weird thing is that when I put that in the function which I want to use it in it outputs nothing, although console.log(M.core_filepicker.instances); outputs the 7 properties when used in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop outputs the correct properties but in an arbitrary order. In Javascript, iteration over properties does not specify the order.

Comment: No, the for loop does not run. It is the output of the first line you are seeing.